# how to speed up fixing translation in rails 3 application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization, rubygems, translation

I have a Rails 3 application, it contains absolute text in its views
`<p>this is what i mean with absolute text</p>`

I have to change this to be `<p><%= t(:translation_of_absolute_text) %><p>`
. I also have to go through the localization file to update it with the new entry!

This is a very long process. I'm looking for a gem that can make it easier.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use redis as a backend and then you can update the key with redis command something like `redis.set('en.us.translation_of_absolute_text','This is my Text') `

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Multi lingual web Translation Center community](http://www.badrit.com/gems/translation_center/) for Rails 3 apps. I think this would be the best tool for what i was looking for.

Thanks to [Badrit](http://www.badrit.com/)